# Where are XP SP1 .cab files located?

Tags: windows-xp, system-file

I have an old firewire device and the docs says that it works better with the SP1 drivers. They have a utility that will install it, but it can't find the *.cab file to install it from. I can get a copy of that from a different machine, but I don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it on a machine that had the original XP "RTM" installed and has had all the updates installed over the years:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Driver Cache\i386\sp1.cab
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends. If you're running a system originally installed using a service pack 2 slipstreamed copy of SP2 though, there is no cab for SP1. You'll only have a separate cabinet for it if you installed using XP RTM, and installed SP1 after it. You might want to take a look at downloading the actual SP1 installer and trying to extract the cabinet file from there.

Comment: I found it looking on an older XP that came with the "RTM". Added an answer with the exact location, but your answer got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all those are on the install discs.

Comment: If only I knew where they were... I've moved since I got this computer... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows XP SP1 or later installation disc, they are located in the i386 directory. SP2 introduced a second CAB file, namely SP2.cab, however generally all the drivers are rolled into a single DRIVER.cab file located in the same place.

Alternatively, some OEMs may place a i386 directory in the root of your Windows partition, which may or may not contain the files you need.

Note: Sometimes the drivers in DRIVER.cab will need system files as well, which can be expanded from the files in the i386 folder, however the whole process is generally made easier by simply installing SP2.

Comment: My understanding is that SP2 replaced the driver with a newer version of the driver that caused problems with this device. That's why I need to find the SP1 files.